# Script to process all images in a single directory using Python

Tags: python, shell

This is what i have tried so far. Images are in .jpg file. I am trying to write a script that can run resize.py to resize all the images at once. No import is used in this .py script

```
for file in *.jpg; do
  python resize.py "$file"
done
```

Error returned to me was

```
  File "test.py", line 2
    for file in *.jpg; do
                ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This is not Python. I think you are confusing a shell script with Python.

Comment: This is Bash code. You can not run it with the Python interpreter.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks. gont confused there a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this with the following, which you would type on the shell (its not Python code):

```
find /path/to/image/dir -name "*.jpg" -exec python /path/to/resize.py {} \;
```

If you want to do this entirely in Python:

```
import glob

from resize import your_resize_function

for image_file in glob.iglob('/path/to/image/dir/*.jpg'):
    your_resize_function(image_file)
```

Here `your_resize_function` is whatever code is running inside `resize.py`.

Comment: can you explain deeper on glob and your_resize_function. What do i replace in your_resize_function?

cause in my resize.py there is involved with open cv.